# New to Arch Linux, problems installing grub

Tags: arch-linux

I've been following along with the arch Linux installation wiki, and when I try to install grub, I either get

```
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `udev`
```

Or

```
/boot doesn't look like an EFI partition
```

Thing is, sda1 is an EFI partition. I'm at a loss, can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Sorry about that, I will. Thanks a million

Comment: And what were the exact commands that led to both error messages? Could the first error have been [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240818)?